# ConfigureAwait(false) when using ContinueWith

Tags: c#

What's the equivalent of using:

```
await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

when using continuations like so (without using the C# compiler's `async/await` transformations)?

```
var taskOfString = ScheduleWorkOnThreadPoolAsync();

// I'd like this continuation to not have to
// "flow" the synchronization context but to simply
// execute wherever it can, i.e. I'd like to tell is
// ConfigureAwait(false) for its previous task.
// How do I do that?
taskOfString.ContinueWith(t => { });


public async Task<string> ScheduleWorkOnThreadPoolAsync()
{
  return Task.Run(() => return "Foo" );
}
```

I am assuming that *doing nothing*, i.e. just leaving it as is is equivalent to calling `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which is also what I see happening when I debug the code. It hops on whatever thread it can.

It is only when we want to specify a scheduler or synchronization context to run the continuation on that we need to pass in extra information to the overload that accepts a `TaskScheduler`. Otherwise, it is defaulted to run without any regard to the execution context.

However, I still request a confirmation or correction if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked into the reference source of [`Task`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs) then `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable` via `GetAwaiter.OnCompleted` back through into `Task.SetContinuationForAwait` (with `continueOnCapturedContext` as `false`), and it drops into:

```
if (!AddTaskContinuation(tc, addBeforeOthers: false))
        tc.Run(this, bCanInlineContinuationTask: false);
```

which is, basically, `ContinueWith`. So: yes.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 but if you're unsure, remember that you can also use `.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(callback)` - not as direct, of course

Comment: Wow! Thank you. That's awesome! :-)

Answer (score 16):

> when using continuations like so (without using the C# compiler's async/await transformations)?

You should almost always use `async`/`await`. They have far safer default behavior. `ContinueWith` is a dangerous, low-level API.

> I am assuming that doing nothing, i.e. just leaving it as is is equivalent to calling ConfigureAwait(false)... It is only when we want to specify a scheduler or synchronization context to run the continuation on that we need to pass in extra information to the overload that accepts a TaskScheduler. Otherwise, it is defaulted to run without any regard to the execution context.

No. This is incorrect, although simple tests won't reveal the problem.

As I describe in my blog post on [why you shouldn't use `ContinueWith`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html), the default `TaskScheduler` for `ContinueWith` is **not** `TaskScheduler.Default`. It's `TaskScheduler.Current`. Since this is confusing in every scenario, *you should **always** pass a `TaskScheduler` to `ContinueWith` and `StartNew`*.

If you want `await x.ConfigureAwait(false)` behavior, you would actually do:

```
var continuation = x.ContinueWith(callback, CancellationToken.None,
    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
    TaskScheduler.Default);
```

The `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` emulates the [synchronous-if-possible behavior of `await`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html). The `TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach` prevents problems if the continuation task is [attached to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417(v=vs.110).aspx) (tasks intended for asynchronous have surprising behavior when child tasks attach to them with `AttachedToParent`). The `TaskScheduler.Default` emulates the `ConfigureAwait(false)` behavior of always executing on a thread pool context.

As a final note, you'll probably need to do something with `continuation` - at least observe it for exceptions and handle them somehow.

At this point, it should be clear why I recommend `await`. At worst, you'd just need to add a helper method to use `await` instead of `ContinueWith` - `await` is much more maintainable, IMO.

Comment: As I understand, providing `TaskScheduler.Default` is the same as supplying flag `TaskContinuationOptions.HideScheduler`.

Comment: @Mike: No; `TaskScheduler.Default` runs the delegate on a thread pool thread. `TaskContinuationOptions.HideScheduler` will ensure `TaskScheduler.Current` is `TaskScheduler.Default`, even if the code is *not* running on the default task scheduler.

Comment: @StephenCleary what that mean? make sure current is default ? you recently said default is thread  pool, and current is current whatever it is to that execution... so it can never be the other thing ... :/

Comment: @deadManN: The terminology here is confusing. The bottom line is that you should *always* pass a `TaskScheduler` to `ContinueWith` (and `StartNew`). The `TaskScheduler.Default` property is the thread pool, but the default value of the `TaskScheduler` instance used by `ContinueWith` and `StartNew` is not `TaskScheduler.Default`. The central takeaway is to always pass a `TaskScheduler`. Or just use `await` instead of `ContinueWith` and `Run` instead of `StartNew`, which will make your code much more maintainable.