# Correct use of ConfigureAwait(false) when chaining tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

So I have a method that chains tasks together to do work

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(1));
tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(2));
tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(3));
tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(4));
tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(5));
tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(6));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

To get better performance/responsiveness out of this method I was looking at using `ConfigureAwait(false)`

The above method does not have any need to run on the same synchronisation context as the calling thread.

what is the correct way to use `ConfigueAwait(false)` when chaining `Tasks` and do I need to use `ConfigureAwait` for each individual task and/or do i need to use it on `Task.WhenAll`

As an extra question...

Does `ConfigureAwait` actually do anything (or improve performance/responsiveness) if there is no code that runs after the await?

Comment: is the number of tasks fixed? or does it vary?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you only need to configure when you need to await, thus you can do it on `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: @MarcGravell it varies

Comment: @user1 please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30671005/1797425) answer by Scott Chamberlain which shows the `correct way` to use `ConfigureAwait`...

Comment: You would *expect* the internal implementation of `Task.WhenAll` to disable sync-context since *it doesn't need it either*, so you *should* just have to use `await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);` (note I removed the `ToArray` - you usually don't need it). However, you could check the github source if unsure...

Comment: @Pac0 What is aggressive about downvotes? Don't take it so personally.

Comment: @MarcGravell from my understanding if you ran `await Task.WhenAll` on the UI Thread then you would expect it to marshall the code after the await back to the UI Thread, which is where my thought of using `ConfigureAwait` came from. Although I could be completely wrong. You can see my confusion

Comment: @Pac0 `but a flock of downvotes was coming in, in less than a few seconds. So... deleted`, maybe the downvoters were typing a response as to why they downvoted?

Comment: @user1 lol, I actually forgot the important bit! have edited the comment, that's my bad sorry

Comment: @Pac0 FWIW, I think your answer was fine and correct; I was trying to upvote it when it died

Comment: @MarcGravell That makes more sense. Thanks! One additional question.. I'm guessing `ConfigureAwait` use applicable regardless of whether code actually runs after the await or not? I looked at the source code for `Task.WhenAll` but its far too complicated for me so I will assume that it already uses `ConfigureAwait` on the task list

Comment: Downvotes are rarely aggressive. In this case it's not clear why one person who knows something about this was about to upvote and three others quickly downvoted. Not a big deal, but clearly there's a little room all around to improve communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so from the comments and chaining a few other questions together I think I have a better understanding of when to use configure await...

All of the below suggestions presume your task does not need to return to the calling thread. i.e. you have a valid `ConfigureAwait` use case

1. **ConfigureAwait configures the await, not the Task - You only need to use `ConfigureAwait` on the line where `await` is used**

   From this answer: [Using ConfigureAwait(false) on tasks passed in to Task.WhenAll() fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670856/using-configureawaitfalse-on-tasks-passed-in-to-task-whenall-fails/30671005#30671005)
2. **You do need to use `ConfigureAwait` even if it is the last line in the method**

   From This answer: [Does Task.ConfigureAwait(false) on the last method line affect anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898665/does-task-configureawaitfalse-on-the-last-method-line-affect-anything)
3. **`ConfigureAwait` doesn't need to be called when using `ContinueWith`**

   From this answer: [ConfigureAwait(false) when using ContinueWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129886/configureawaitfalse-when-using-continuewith)
4. **Tasks contained in `Task.WhenAll` are already configured with `ConfigureAwait`**

   Also from this answer: [Using ConfigureAwait(false) on tasks passed in to Task.WhenAll() fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670856/using-configureawaitfalse-on-tasks-passed-in-to-task-whenall-fails/30671005#30671005)

Which leaves me with my code looking like so:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(1));
tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(2));
tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(3));
tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(4));
tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(5));
tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(6));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

To my surprise it seems that using `ConfigureAwait` is advised by most of the community, although when talking about Threading/async/await this never really gets a mention.

**Extra information:** [Why would I bother to use Task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851073/why-would-i-bother-to-use-task-configureawaitcontinueoncapturedcontext-false)

I'm not an expert in this field I've just linked together relevent other questions, so if I've missed anything / got anything wrong, feel free to chip in.

Comment: I would phrase (1) as "`ConfigureAwait` configures the `await`, not the `Task`". Ignore `ContinueWith`; it's a low-level, dangerous operation that should almost never be used in modern code.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary. I'm interrested in finding out more about avoiding `ContinueWith`. Have you got any links with information about the problems with it/ avoiding it / alternatives / any valid use cases

Comment: The best alternative for `ContinueWith` is `await`. To use properly, you [always have to pass a `TaskScheduler`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). Finally, it's just plain awkward to pass a delegate continuation rather than just continuing the `async` method.